# Comando SELECT negado ao usuário

Tags: php, mysql, sql-select

> Erro: SELECT command denied to user 'banco'@'xxx.xx.xx.xx' for table 'table'

Este erro só acontece na minha hospedagem, está rodando local perfeitamente, estou consultando 2 bancos de dados em uma unica query usando:

```
 `banco`.`table` ...
```

Será que é permissões do usuário? Se sim, como posso liberar a permissão, lembrando que é hospedagem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse erro é gerado quando estás a tentar aceder a uma base de dados com um utilizador que não tem permissões sobre a mesma.

Para o teu caso em particular, o utilizador que está a tentar aceder não tem permissões para executar o `SELECT` nessa base de dados.

Confirma se o utilizador existe e se tem permissões para aceder à base de dados, caso não, deverás criar um utilizador e associar o mesmo a base de dados em questão.

A forma para criar o utilizador e associar o mesmo à base de dados vai depender do teu alojamento, mas certamente tens acesso a um painel de administração tipo cPanel onde podes aceder para criar contas de correio, bases de dados e seus utilizadores.

---

Em casos excepcionais, já foi [reportado no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5668611/352449) que em consultas que trabalham com duas ou mais tabelas e:

- uma delas não existir;
- ou existir um erro no `SELECT` onde o nome da tabela está mal escrito

O MySQL ao invés de dar a indicação que a tabela não existe, apresenta a mensagem de erro de falta de permissões do utilizador em relação ao `SELECT` em execução.

Confirma também que as tabelas existem na base de dados do teu alojamento.

Comment: Olá, tua resposta está correta, verificando todos os meus dados e script percebo que realmente o usuário não tem permissão, porém as tabelas existem conforme o script. Na minha hospedagem, cada banco de dados tem um usuário diferente, oque realizo no meu script é conectar aos dois bancos de dados com os diferentes usuários, porém no Query ele usa apenas um usuário para acessar os dois bancos de dados. Teria como fazer para o query procurar por exemplo *`conexao1`.`banco1`.`tabela1`.`id1`* e *`conexao2`.`banco2`.`tabela2`.`id2`*?

Comment: Ele está a usar as mesmas credenciais de acesso provavelmente porque ao efectuares as consultas não estás a consultar usando a ligação correcta. Tens que estabelecer uma ligação para cada base de dados dados os utilizadores serem diferentes, guardas cada ligação numa variável e fazes a consulta pela variável correcta: `$conexao1 = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');` e para a 2ª `$conexao2 = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass')` fazendo consulta para o banco1 `$resultados = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fooBar", $conexao1)`.

Comment: Mas e quando consulto duas tabelas com diferentes conexões? não da pra fazer `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fooBar", $conexao1, $conexao2)`...  e ai?